# "Fileexists" on remote directory does not see removed file fast enough

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, file-exists

I have an application that checks if a file has been deleted on a remote folder.

So I use fileexists, and if it returns that there's no file, I can proceed with the proccess. But when the remote file is deleted, the computer doesn't "notice" it until after 7-8 seconds.

If I execute it on the same PC that has the file, it's almost instantaneous.

How can I force the application to look for the file in the real folder instead in its cache?

Thank's in advance

Comment: You cannot force the app to ignore the cache. The APIs involved in querying remote file information use the cache internally, so you have to wait for the cache to be updated. On Windows, there are Registry settings to tweak the lifetime values of the cache, see [this MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/10/file-exists-access-getfileattributes-findfirstfile-findnextfile-stat-behavior-over-smb-2-0.aspx) for details. FYI, `FileExists()` uses `GetFileAttributes()` and `FindFirstFile()` on Windows.

Comment: You can try to monitor file removal using FindFirstChangeNotification  API. It can potentially work faster. And try to check how fast Windows Explorer "notice" file removal

Comment: @Rem try being the key word here.  1. There is no guarantee that change notifications will be fired, that is up to the serving mechanism.  2. Even if the serving mechanism generates notifications, there is no guarantee that every monitored location will fire off an event for every registered change.

Comment: @Rem As far as I know FindFirstChangeNotification does not work for remote folders unless you have set up active synchronization of that folder. And even then you would be experiencing certain delays. So this would probably not solve OP problem.